# All Data Transformations via SSIS

Tags: data-warehouse, ssis-2016

Some folks here at my current job have made the decision that all data transformations that go into our database must be done via SSIS. This means that any old code such as views, stored procedures, functions, etc. that are used to transform data will no longer be used. The transformations they currently perform will be done via SSIS only. I am trying to come up with a list of potential issues we may face and I don't know as much about SSIS as I do about SQL Server being that I am a DBA here. One of the issues I see is attempting to look at performance issues in SSIS vs sql objects. What are the other things I am missing? We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP2 and SSIS 2016.

Comment: It also being proposed that if a stored procedure contains logic unable to be implemented in SSIS, that stored procedure should return the transformed data in a resultset so the transformed data may be moved via SSIS package rather than update a physical table as a means of standardizing. Wouldn't this make two calls to the optimizer rather than one and be much less performant?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this done.  And while it's not something I would ever recommend, it does have some advantages from a process and skillset point-of-view.  The main reason you would try this is to have a consistent drag-and-drop process for building, and importantly, changing ETL processes.

Issues:

1) Performance.  Performing transformations in SSIS data flows is just slower than using TSQL.

2) Productivity.  Using TSQL is, perhaps, a more difficult skill, but for someone who can do both, it's massively more productive to build and test using TSQL than SSIS data flows.

Answer (score 0):

I like David's answer, and I'd use that to present an argument "against" SSIS.

However if you want a happy medium, you can also have SSIS use the procedures/views as script tasks for organization and visualization/flow purposes.

For example: I use the Hybrid form to:

1. Get Data from another DB/Table/Flat file (Via Source)
2. If a flat file was used, move it from an import directory into a "working directory"
3. Transform/validate the data via a Script task (C#)
4. Push the data to a staging table (Via Execute SQL Task with an underlying T-sql procedure)
5. Merge/Upsert it into the final destination table (Via Execute SQL Task with an underlying procedure)
6. Log the Imported/Updated rows to a table (via Execute SQL Task with an underlying procedure)
7. Rename/Move the file (if a file was used) to an archive directory (Via Copy/Move file task)
8. Send an Email that the package was done (and stats per file) (via Send Email task)

This way when someone looks at my ETL processes, they can easily tell the flow and find the objects in question, but I can still have the "modularity" of a package with the T-SQL Components.

This also makes replicating my process a lot easier.  if there's a new table, I just copy/paste (to a degree) and tweak the process to the new components.  I have template packages that already have my dev/prod/qa connections/directories, which makes things much more manageable.